# PushNotifications iOS 7 not working when user taps on icon

Tags: objective-c, ios7, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I have the methods below to handle push notifications. They work perfect when the app is running and I do receive notifications when the app is in the background. When a user taps the icon however it opens the app but my UICollection view is not reloaded the way it is when a user receives the notification when the app is running.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        // do stuff when app is active
        NSString *cancelTitle = @"Close";
        NSString *showTitle = @"Ok";
        NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
        NSString *type = [userInfo objectForKey:@"type"];

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Linkedstar"
                                                            message:message
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                                  otherButtonTitles:showTitle, nil];

        if([type isEqualToString:@"message"]) {
            alertView.tag = alertMessage;
        }
        else if([type isEqualToString:@"post"]) {
            alertView.tag = post;
        }
        else if([type isEqualToString:@"contact"]) {
            alertView.tag = contact;
        }

        [alertView show];

        [self presentViewForPush:userInfo updateUI:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        // do stuff when app is in background
        NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
        [self handlePush:userInfo updateUI:YES];
    }
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDictionary *pushDict = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if(pushDict)
    {
        [self handlePush:pushDict updateUI:YES];
    }
}
```

I need help figuring out how to handle the launchOptions data when the user taps on the icon.I have tried a couple of different options after doing some research online and non worked.
any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this [Scheduling, Registering, and Handling Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)

> If the action button is tapped (on a device running iOS), the system
>   launches the application and the application calls its delegate’s
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (if implemented); it
>   passes in the notification payload (for remote notifications) or the
>   local-notification object (for local notifications).
>
> If the **application icon is tapped** on a device running iOS, the
>   application calls the same method, but furnishes **no information** about
>   the notification

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense then. It explains what i'm experiencing. It sucks that an action can't be triggered when a user taps on the icon after they receive a notification.

Comment: @emm You'd better read Apple documents first, its very helpful. You can accept this answer if you like

Answer (score 3):

**1)**  **When application is running in background** and **When application is running in foreground**
`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method will called as below.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
     {
     //opened from a push notification when the app was on background

       NSLog(@"userInfo->%@",[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]);
     }
  else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
     {
     // a push notification when the app is running. So that you can display an alert and push in any view

        NSLog(@"userInfo->%@",[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]);
     }
}
```

**2)**  **When application is not launched (close)** than `application:didFinishedLaunchWithOptions`method will called.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
         //opened from a push notification when the app is closed
        NSDictionary* userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (userInfo != nil)
        {
             NSLog(@"userInfo->%@",[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]);
        }

    }
     else{
             //opened app without a push notification.
         }
}
```

Comment: Oh cool thanks for the tip, i'll make the appropriate changes to my didReceiveRemoteNotification method.

Answer (score 0):

Handling notifications is done in either didReceiveRemoteNotification (app is "alive") or didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (app was "dead").

I don't think you can handle these notifications if the user simply taps on the icon.  They must go through the notification itself.

Comment: thanks, I guess I will just have to reload my collection view when they tap they icon in order to update my cells.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: if user clicks on push banner he gets info of push in app, if he clicks on app icon he doesn't get it. You can handle derivative one from it, but with some limits only. Example, if you want to have a badge number from push, you can do it:
(Push -> App icon -> App icon badge -> your var)

in AppDelegate

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{ 
    newMessages = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber;
}
```