# To display all the notifications delivered to IOS device using Urban Air Ship

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I want to display all the notifications delivered (To IOS Device) within my application.

So how would I get all notifications objects when app is switching from dead to active state?

I am using urban air ship for push notification.

Can I retrieve previous notifications delivered when app is in dead state in  `"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions"`?

According to me there is no possibility.

Comment: Like message delivered to someone on some time .. is it this way you are saying ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access notification object until User interact with notification from Notification Center or App is in foreground. 
You may check which method is calling when push notification arrives in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22978277/1540450).

You may search for list of push sent in [Urban Airship Document](http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/). You may find something in their document or can connect their support team.

Comment: can i get when it is in background.

Comment: no you can't get it untill user interact with notification if in background,